# Print a Header's Children (Org-Mode)

Tags: org-mode

With an tree like

```
* Parent
** Sub-Parent1
** Sub-Parent2
```

...how can one get a list of all of the sub-parents? Perhaps printing them as follows:

```
Sub-Parent1; Sub-Parent2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a basic function that retrieves subheadings and a basic example of its usage with your example:

```
(defun ebpa/get-subheadings (&optional recursive)
  "Return a list of subheadings.  If RECURSIVE is truthy return a
list of all headings in subheading subtrees."
  (org-save-outline-visibility t
    (save-excursion
      (let ((pred (lambda () (org-entry-get nil "ITEM"))))
        (if recursive
            (org-map-entries pred nil 'tree)
          (progn
            (org-back-to-heading t)
            (org-show-subtree)
            (if (org-goto-first-child)
                (cl-loop collect (funcall pred)
                         until (let ((pos (point)))
                                 (null (org-forward-heading-same-level nil t))
                                 (eq pos (point)))))))))))

(message (string-join (ebpa/get-subheadings) "; "))
;; => "Sub-Parent1; Sub-Parent2"
```